# SMTP Connector for SBS 2008 (1and1 and rogers are not working)

Tags: exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008, smtp, 1and1

I need an SMTP connector for my SBS 2008 server.
The Domain/DNS is registered with 1and1 but due to recent issues they are being blocked by a lot of servers now.
1and1 also does not give me enough control over my DNS to allow me to setup the proper DNS records to allow me to effectivly use that as an option.
Also my ISP Rogers, now requires you to setup every non Rogers email address in order to allow sending through there SMTP. Also they limit me to 10 addresses which is not enough for me.

Can anyone reccomend a solution to any of the above, or a good relaiable, affoardable SMTP server to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the cheapest fix would be to switch your Domain and DNS to another company like [Namecheap](http://www.namecheap.com) for about 10 bucks/year.

The next most expensive option would be [postini](http://www.google.com/postini/compare.html) for $12 per user /year. Postini will provide an outbound and incoming smtp service. Also, [mimecast](http://www.mimecast.com) provides a great service but costs a bit more.

Comment: +1 Postini's outbound smarthost service has been a Godsend (and their incoming spam filtering ain't too shabby either).

Comment: What about a service like https://secure.authsmtp.com/signup/? or http://www.authsmtp.com/?gclid=CMy_xs-pyqYCFY64KgodFWbxHw how do they compare postini?

Comment: With Postini, you're paying for the spam filtering: they just let you use the outbound SMTP smarthost for relaying (and filtering) mail out of for free.  For ~$3.50 a mailbox per month, it does a great job filtering spam.  There's also the spool feature that'll hold your mail if/when your mail server goes down.

Comment: I have ended up purchasing hosting service from my ISP which includes outgoing SMTP which I can use for Exchange which was reasonable at $10/month